# What is this in Ruby, and why does it exist?

Tags: ruby

Is it an array? What is its structure and usage? Why does it exist in Ruby?

```
>> Z =  x=1 , y =2 , a =3 , b=4


=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Why does this array support initialization? Can it be of any potential use? Why did the designers of Ruby support such an esoteric array declaration?

Comment: It's Ruby. Typically, when they could add something, they did. Ruby has tons of things like this, and you pretty much need to know them all because someone out there likes to use them.

Comment: It's not limited to Ruby. Perl can do something very similar: `@z = ($a=1,$b=2)`. My question is why? It isn't more legible and the space savings are negligible.

Answer (score 5):

It's one of those things that can be done but probably shouldn't because it hides what its intention is behind a thin veil of cleverness, making it harder to maintain.

Basically, it's assigning an array to `Z` while initializing the other variables.

```
Z =  x=1 , y =2 , a =3 , b=4 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
Z #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
x #=> 1
```

Personally, in a code review I'd ask the programmer to write it one of these ways:

```
Z = [1, 2, 3, 4]

x, y, a, b = *Z
```

or

```
(x, y, a, b) = Z
```

Comment: why not use `x, y, a, b = Z`? is there any problem? I am getting the desired result.

Comment: You can do that too. I prefer the others because they remind me that I'm bursting an array into separate variables, but your mileage might vary.

Comment: ok..got it..I asked because I am accustomed to seeing code snippets like `a, b = [1, 2]`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say this is more of a side effect of the ability to do multiple variable assignment than a way to purposefully initialize an array.

In Ruby, you can assign multiple values at once using an array, you can return multiple values from a method. This gets returned as an array as well. Furthermore, since *every expression* in Ruby has a return value, `x = 1, y = 2` returns the values for both of the assignment operations in an array as well.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > a, b = 3, 4
 => [3, 4] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > a
 => 3 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > b
 => 4 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > def my_method
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005?>   return "value1", "value2"
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > my_method
 => ["value1", "value2"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > x = my_method
 => ["value1", "value2"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009 > x, y = my_method
 => ["value1", "value2"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :010 > x
 => "value1" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :011 > y
 => "value2"
```